# How python asyncIO, suspend & resume the task?

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-3.5, python-asyncio, event-loop

A style of programming in which task release the CPU during waiting periods, so that other tasks can use it.

To introduce an async task,

- A task should be capable to suspend & resume
- An event scheduler should schedule those tasks(when ready)

Wrote event [scheduler](https://github.com/shamhub/Design_pattern/blob/master/EventHandling-Observer_pattern/eventloop.py), but stuck in enabling an async [task](https://github.com/shamhub/Design_pattern/blob/master/EventHandling-Observer_pattern/subject.py#L26). Assume the task being IO bound. Scheduler does not get CPU slice, amidst  task execution, because task gets executed synchronously.

---

A task(`bar`) in python, becomes async task(capable to suspend & resume), when task uses `async`, `await` **keywords** with `ayncio.onSomeIO` capable wait,

```
async def bar():
   await asyncio.onSomeIO()
```

---

**Question:**

How `asyncio` package enables `bar`, to be an async task, with these keywords, under the hood?  Does each task get launched on separate thread?

Comment: You might want to look at the following [article from Brett Cannon](https://snarky.ca/how-the-heck-does-async-await-work-in-python-3-5/) about what is under the hood for async/await. It's very in depth, but it's not a topic that could be covered easily on S/O.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Does each task get launched on separate thread?

No, usually asyncio runs in single thread.

> How asyncio package enables bar, to be an async task, with these
>   keywords, under the hood?

When you define function as `async` this function becomes generator what allows to execute it "by steps" using `__next__()` method. `await` - is `yield` (`yield from` actually) point where execution flow returns to global event loop that manages executing of all coroutines.

This simple example shows how you can switch between execution flow of different generators:

```
def task(i):
    yield 1
    print('task {}: step 1'.format(i))
    yield 2
    print('task {}: step 2'.format(i))


tasks = [
    task(1),
    task(2),
    task(3),
]


def execute_tasks(tasks):
    i = 0
    finished = []
    while True:
        # start executing tasks:
        try:
            tasks[i].__next__()
        except StopIteration:
            finished.append(i)
        # check if any task unfinished:
        if len(finished) == len(tasks):
            return
        # move to next unfinished task:
        while True:
            i += 1
            if i > len(tasks) - 1:
                i = 0
            if not i in finished:
                break


if __name__ == '__main__':
    execute_tasks(tasks)
```

Output:

```
task 1: step 1
task 2: step 1
task 3: step 1
task 1: step 2
task 2: step 2
task 3: step 2
```

`asyncio` of course is much more complex and allows you much more.

Probably best explanation of how you can implement coroutines using generators I saw in this PyCon 2015 video: [David Beazley - Python Concurrency From the Ground Up: LIVE!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MCs5OvhV9S4) ([source code](https://github.com/dabeaz/concurrencylive/blob/master/aserver.py)). You should definitely watch it if you're going implement this.

But I advice you to use `asyncio` instead - it already exists for you, there's no need to invent your own.

Comment: Instead of `yield 1` can we request for some IO bound operation? I have this code [here](https://github.com/shamhub/DataProcsngAnalytics/tree/master/1_Pipeline_processing) without event-loop

Comment: @overexchange try to look at code from video I gave link to above (I added link to code there). `run()` there - is actually event loop. 1) It tells tasks to execute until I/O operations (line 43) 2) tasks yield on I/O operations to return control to event loop (lines 82, 88, 94, 96) 3) when event loop see all tasks pending it uses `select` to wait some I/O done (line 33).

Comment: Pycon presentation is amazing. Not sure, how did I miss?